# Showing this space is complete

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $(c_0,\|\space.\|_{\infty})$ be the space of sequences $(x_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ such that $x_k\in{}\mathbb{K}$ and $x_k\rightarrow{}0$. I want to show that this space is complete.

I understand this requires me to take a Cauchy sequence in $c_0$ and showing it not only converges, but converges to a limit point (a sequence) in $c_0$.

I am comfortable with the definitions, but I am not sure how to approach the proof. This is how I tried to break down the problem:

Clearly a Cauchy sequence is bounded and I believe it does converge but can't show why (I can easily show that a convergence implies Cauchy).

After this, knowing it converges, I must show it converges to a sequence that itself converges to 0.

I did find a similar question someone else has posted but didn't find the solution very helpful.

Comment: this will do just fine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275810/show-that-c-0-is-a-banach-space-with-the-norm-rvert-cdot-lvert-infty

Comment: I believe so, thank you. Apologies for the repeated question.